# Image failed to download in KakaoTalk

Tags: windows-7, kakaotalk

I have noticed that many images that people had sent me a while ago fail to download in KakaoTalk:

[image]

Is it impossible to access images that were sent a long time ago in KakaoTalk? If so, after how many days do images become inaccessible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to access images that were sent a while ago in KakaoTalk.